# JQuery processing interactive content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, interactive

I noticed that in jquery appended text won't be processed by jquery functions. For example, you append a code containing dropdown-list and you have a function that invokes on changing its value. This function works on existing code only, not on appended one.

---

And the correct answer is:

Instead of using:

```
$('#purchase-table select').change(function() {
});
```

Use:

```
$('#purchase-table select').live('change', function() {
});
```

You need it to be able to process ajax-appended content by your jquery functions. Have a nice day.

Thanks to everyone helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JQuery .live()

Append new content:

```
$('body').append('<div class="clickme">Another target</div>');
```

Add handler to it:

```
$('.clickme').live('click', function() {
  // Live handler called.
});
```

Then clicks on the new element will also trigger the handler.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to handle events on interactive content is the `jQuery.live` method.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

> Description: Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

Comment: Thanks, Ghommey, I'll check this too.